# When is earliest mention of the Church tradition that Jesus was born in a cave?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, tradition, christmas, birth-of-jesus

The birth of Jesus as recounted by Luke says that:

> **7** And she gave birth to her first-born son and wrapped him in swaddling cloths, and laid him in a manger, because there was no place
>   for them in the inn. [Cf. Luke 2:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202%3A7&version=RSVCE).

How did it come to be known in Church Tradition that Jesus was born in a cave, and when is earliest mention of this tradition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest reference I can find is Justin Martyr (c. 100 – 165 AD) who wrote in [Dialog With Trypho](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.viii.iv.i.html):

> But when the Child was born in Bethlehem, since Joseph could not find
>   a lodging in that village, he took up his quarters in a certain **cave**
>   near the village; and while they were there Mary brought forth the
>   Christ and placed Him in a manger. ([1](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.viii.iv.lxxviii.html))

Answer (score 3):

There is a short prequel to the gospels called the [Protevangelium of James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_James), supposedly written about 150 ad., but it is noncanonical and certainly not an eyewitness account. The author claims to have been walking in a field and this vision just came to him. Although I don't believe that it is authentic history, it does mention Mary going into a cave with her midwife, and there is a big flash of light when Jesus is born. Interesting, but nothing more.

Comment: The protoevangelium is noncanonical, but it is traditionally considered to be historically accurate